# Finding out if a class is a subclass of another class (Objective-C)

Tags: objective-c, oop

So I have a Class object, say for class 'D'.  Is there a way to figure out if that class object is a subclass of another Class object, say 'B'?  I tried `-isKindOfClass:` and `isMemberOfClass`, but neither worked.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use class method [+isSubclassOfClass](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Answer (score 1):

Well hello there Grimless!

`-isKindOfClass:` should work fine, it says so in the documentation: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html

But there is another class method in `NSObject` called `+isSubclassOfClass:` that you should use instead.

Comment: Kickass!  Thanks.  That's exactly what I needed.  Didn't find it because Xcode doesn't recognize +isSubclassOfClass on Class, weird.  Still sharp, as always, eh Jacob? :P  Here's what I did:if (c1 == first || [c1 isSubclassOfClass:first])
 {
  if (c2 == second || [c2 isSubclassOfClass:second])
  {
   return YES;
  }
 }
 else if (c1 == second || [c1 isSubclassOfClass:second])
 {
  if (c2 == first || [c2 isSubclassOfClass:first])
  {
   return YES;
  }
 }
 
 return NO;